# Message Input Bar not pushing up the screen. Using IQKeyboard manage pushing the navigation bar also but I don't want that. #messagekit

Tags: messagekit

Using the Message Kit to chat with users. Message Input Bar is not pushed up while typing. Is there anything needed to do for this.

Comment: Please share your code so people can analyze it. The more information you share with the community, the easier it will be for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ViewController is conforming to the InputBarAccessoryViewDelegate.

Whilst the simulator is open, click on I/O > Keyboard > Deselect Connect Hardware Keyboard from the menu bar. Re-run simulator and the keyboard should expand upon selection of the input bar.